# Force Google Colab to use R kernel for existing notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have several existing Jupyter notebooks that use R instead of python.

When I open these notebooks in Colab, sometimes it will automatically use the R kernel (ir), and other times it will use Jupyter3 (which results in all the code being broken). I can't figure out why it uses the R kernel for one notebook but not for another.

Is there a way to manually change the kernel to R? Or some code to include that ensures Colab will recognize the notebook as being an R notebook and not a Python notebook?

I know that I can start a new notebook with the R kernel using https://colab.research.google.com/#create=true&language=r. If you go to Runtime -> Change runtime type, then you can select between the R and Python 3 kernels. However, that only works for new notebooks.

If I open an existing notebook that doesn't use automatically use the R kernel, if I go to Runtime -> Change runtime type, it only shows me options to change the Hardware acceleration options. It doesn't allow me to manually select the R kernel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For standard Jupyter, there's metadata that gets stored in the header or footer of the notebook file as a record of what kernel it was saved with. If you open both of the files in a text editor, and then examine the very top and bottom the one where it works and compare the very top and bottom of the one that doesn't, you should see something about `irkernel`, I suspect. Maybe it is the same for Colab?

Comment: Thanks @Wayne. Manually including the metadata seemed to help. One time, it seemed like I was able to override this metadata by having the first line of code be invalid R code (the package was installed on my computer but not in Colab).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like including the following metadata just before the final "}" of the raw file corrected the issue:

```
  "metadata": {
    "kernelspec": {
      "name": "ir",
      "display_name": "R",
      "language": "R"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of [jfrench](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75494897/1575670), I had to change the meta as follows to make it work with Google Colab:

```
 "metadata": {
    "colab": {
      "provenance": []
    },
    "language_info": {
      "codemirror_mode": {
        "name": "R"
      },
      "file_extension": ".py",
      "mimetype": "text/x-python",
      "name": "python",
      "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
      "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
      "version": "3.10.8"
    }
```

I simply replaced `"name": "ipython", "version": 3` by `"name": "R"`.